# Inserting the values in SQL Database, returning them added together and comparing the reult

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I have a database, a main activity, and 4 buttons. I tried to make the buttons send a number value to the database when clicked, and then when another button is clicked to display a View that has a number value attached, that is egual to the sum of those 4 buttons clicked.

How can I assign a number value to the click of buttons and send the value to the database I have?
And how can I add(sum) the values from the database and compare them to a value that I want?

```
classdbOpenHelper.class

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class classdbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NUMBER = "btnumber";
    public static final String KEY_RESULT = "result";


    public static final String DATABASE_NAME= "data";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tabel";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    public classdbOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " +
                KEY_NUMBER + " INTEGER " +
                KEY_RESULT + " INTEGER); " 
                ); 
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXITS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }}
```

MainActivity.class

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    DBAdapter myDb;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_goto_start);

        openDB ();



        //Buttons for start screen
        ImageButton clicks =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.clicks);
        ImageButton new_test_btn =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.new_test_btn);
        ImageButton view_profile_btn =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.view_profile_btn);
        ImageButton home_btn =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_btn);
        ImageButton info_btn =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.info_btn);
        //Buttons for question_1
        Button a1_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.a1_btn);
        Button b1_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1_btn);
        Button next_btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.next_btn1);
        //Buttons for question_2
        Button a2_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.a2_btn);
        Button b2_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2_btn);
        Button next_btn2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.next_btn2);
        Button back_btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.back_btn1);
        //Buttons for question_3
        Button a3_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.a3_btn);
        Button b3_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b3_btn);
        Button next_btn3 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.next_btn3);
        Button back_btn2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.back_btn2);
        //Buttons for question_4
        Button a4_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.a3_btn);
        Button b4_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b3_btn);
        Button result_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.result_btn);
        Button back_btn3 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.back_btn3);
        //Answers
        ScrollView eerner =(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.eerner_scroll);



        //Click on screen to start
        clicks.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override    
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View startpage = (View)findViewById(R.id.startpage);
                View homepage = (View)findViewById(R.id.homepage);

                homepage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                startpage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);};});

        //Click a1 and b1 !!!!!!!
        a1_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override    
            public void onClick(View v) {
                long newId = myDb.insertRow("A1", 1);
            };});


        //Click result
        result_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override    
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();
                displayRecordSet(cursor);
            }

            private void displayRecordSet(Cursor cursor) {
                String message = "Hi";

                if(cursor.getLong(columnIndex))

                    displayText(message);

            }


            ;});


        //Click for question_1
        new_test_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View startpage = (View)findViewById(R.id.startpage);
                View question_1 = (View)findViewById(R.id.question_1);

                startpage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                question_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);};});

        //Click for question_2
        next_btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View question_1 = (View)findViewById(R.id.question_1);
                View question_2 = (View)findViewById(R.id.question_2);

                question_1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                question_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);};});

        //Go back to question_1
        back_btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View question_2 = (View)findViewById(R.id.question_2);
                View question_1 = (View)findViewById(R.id.question_1);

                question_2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                question_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);};});

        //Click for question_3
        next_btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View question_2 = (View)findViewById(R.id.question_2);
                View question_3 = (View)findViewById(R.id.question_3);

                question_2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                question_3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);};});

        //Go back to question_2
        back_btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View question_3 = (View)findViewById(R.id.question_3);
                View question_2 = (View)findViewById(R.id.question_2);

                question_3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                question_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);};});

        //Click for question_4
        next_btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View question_3 = (View)findViewById(R.id.question_3);
                View question_4 = (View)findViewById(R.id.question_4);

                question_3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                question_4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);};});

        //Go back to question_3
        back_btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View question_4 = (View)findViewById(R.id.question_4);
                View question_3 = (View)findViewById(R.id.question_3);

                question_4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                question_3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);};});

        //Click for info screen
        info_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View startpage = (View)findViewById(R.id.startpage);
                ScrollView frameinfo = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.frameinfo);
                View answers = (View)findViewById(R.id.answers);

                startpage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                frameinfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                answers.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);};});

        //Click for home
        home_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View startpage = (View)findViewById(R.id.startpage);
                View homepage = (View)findViewById(R.id.homepage);

                startpage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                homepage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);};});

        //Click for view profile
        view_profile_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View startpage = (View)findViewById(R.id.startpage);
                View answers = (View)findViewById(R.id.answers);
                ScrollView eerner_scroll = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.eerner_scroll);

                startpage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                eerner_scroll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                answers.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);};});

    }



    private void openDB() {
        myDb = new DBAdapter(this);
        myDb.open();

    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        closeDB();
    }

    private void closeDB() {
        myDb.close();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.goto_start, menu);
        return true;
    }}
```

Comment: you missed the comas in the create query.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with following Columns:

a) buttonId  : The Id of one of four buttons referenced(may be 1,2,3 & 4)

b) Value     : The Value to be stored on button click

Insert Initial values to this table in overridden onCreate method of SQLiteOpenHelper  class.
Insert following values (1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0) as (buttonId,Value)

On button Click in you Activity, Update the column-Value of the row having corresponding buttonId among 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 in this case. This is how you can assign a number value to the click of buttons and send the value to the database.

Then fetch all columns of the table into a cursor, read column "value" of each row in the cursor one by one add it to a variable.This is how you can I add(sum) the values from the database and compare them to a value that you want.

Hope this bit helps your cause...

Comment: Can you please show an example of code that I can adapt! Thanks!